# JS send data twice?

Tags: javascript

I create code to get data with js
but i find problem JS send data twice
this my JS code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function last_msg_funtion() { 
        var ID=$(".message_box:last").attr("id");
        $('#last_msg_loader').html('<img src="wait.gif">');
        $.post("index.php?action=get&last_msg_id="+ID, function(data) {
            if (data != "") {
                $(".message_box:last").after(data);         
            }
            $('#last_msg_loader').empty();
        });
        return false;
    };  

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
           last_msg_funtion();
        }
    }); 
    return false;
});
```

How I can fix this problem ?

Comment: scroll fires many times very fast, you need to "debounce" it

Comment: How i can do that @dandavis ??

Comment: Do you have to use $(window).scroll to send data? That seems like a terrible practice.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `.one()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function last_msg_funtion() { 
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
          var ID=$(".message_box:last").attr("id");
          $('#last_msg_loader').html('<img src="wait.gif">');
          $.post("index.php?action=get&last_msg_id="+ID, function(data) {
            if (data != "") {
                $(".message_box:last").after(data);         
            }
            $('#last_msg_loader').empty();
            $(window).one("scroll", last_msg_funtion0)
          });             
        }
        $(window).one("scroll", last_msg_funtion0)
        return false;
    };  

    $(window).one("scroll", last_msg_funtion0); 
});
```

Comment: @grandor See updated post, added `$(window).one("scroll", last_msg_funtion0)` outside of `if` condition

Comment: The problem gets when page scroll fast
I think the solution is make code wait some seconds.
if you know how do do that edit my code

Comment: Try substituting greater than  `>` or less than `<` operator at `$(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()`, for `==` depending on expected result.  Should `$(window).scrollTop()` be greater than `$(document).height() - $(window).height()` , or within a given range of pixels ?